# Having trouble with readline() function Python

Tags: python, readline

In my program, I open a file whose name the user enters in, planning to read and append the file (a+). I use seek(0) to move the pointer to the beginning of the file because it starts out at the end of the file when using a+. I then use the readline() function, and check if what the program read from the line was in a tuple. Here is the code:

```
fileName = input()
fileName += ".txt"
file = open(fileName, "a+")
fileName += ","
print("Opened", fileName, "reading:")
print()

#Reading operation selection
file.seek(0)
operation = file.readline() #Line 0 = operation
if operation not in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
    print("Did not find valid operation in file.")
    print("Use a file with valid calculation code:")
    continue
```

I have a text file 'file.txt' containing exactly the following:

```
+
12
12
c
```

When I run the program and enter 'file', it returns 'Opened file.txt, reading: Did not find valid operation in file. Use a file with valid calculation code:'. *So,* I troubleshooted and ran the following code in a separate file:

```
fileName = input()
fileName += ".txt"
file = open(fileName, "a+")
fileName += ","
print("Opened", fileName, "reading:")
print()

#Reading operation selection
file.seek(0)
operation = file.readline() #Line 0 = operation

print(operation)

if operation not in ('+', '-', '*', '/'):
    print("Did not find valid operation in file.")
    print("Use a file with valid calculation code:")
    continue
```

I ran this program, entered 'file' as the file name, and it returns:
    Opened file.txt, reading:

```
+

Did not find valid operation in file.
Use a file with valid calculation code:
```

Why does the variable operation contain the single character that is the first line of file.txt and then a blank line after it?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because Pythons `readline` also returns the newline at the end of the line. E.g. `readline() -> "+\n"`.

You can use `rstrip("\n")` to remove the newline from your lines. E.g. `readline().rstrip("\n")`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 if operation.strip() not in ('+', '-', '*', '/')
```

You need to remove the newline.

Comment: You should really use `rstrip("\n")` instead of `strip()`.

Comment: @robert, why would I need rstrip on a single character and why would anyone need to specify the "\n". I think you need to read the documentation

Comment: I don't know what the upvote for roberts comment is for, it is completely inaccurate

Comment: Just using `strip()` may mask other, unrelated errors, because it removes *all* whitespace on *both* sides. In this case we want to remove the *trailing* newline - and therefore `rstrip("\n")` is exactly what we need.

Comment: There is one character so your comment is inaccurate and you don't need to use \n

Comment: You presuppose that the input file is well-formatted and doesn't contain any whitespace other than trailing newlines. As a programmer, I don't like superfluous whitespace and therefore, would like to treat such whitespaces as errors.

Comment: That statement makes even less sense